# Views in Idris - Listing 10.5 of Type-Driven Development in Idris book

Tags: types, idris

Presently I am working my way through Edwin Brady's  "Type-Driven Development with Idris" text. Needless to mention, the text lists code for both SplitList and splitList (cover function).However, I wonder if the cover function given in the text could be simplified to the one that I produce below - which doesn't work as intended. Could someone please let me know why my splitList doesn't work? The error message that I receive is produced further below. Many thanks.

```
data SplitList : List ty -> Type where
  Null      : SplitList [ ]
  Singleton : SplitList [x]
  Pair      : (lhs: List ty) -> (rhs: List ty) -> SplitList (lhs ++ rhs)

splitList : (xs: List ty) -> SplitList xs
splitList [ ] = Null
splitList [x] = Singleton
splitList xs  = 
  let 
    mid = div (List.length xs) 2 
    lhs = List.take mid xs
    rhs = List.drop mid xs
  in
    Pair lhs rhs
```

### Error Message:

Type checking ./foo.idr
foo.idr:53:11:
When checking right hand side of splitList with expected type
        SplitList xs

Type mismatch between
        SplitList (lhs ++ rhs) (Type of Pair lhs rhs)
and
        SplitList xs (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                lhs ++ rhs
        and
                xs
Holes: Main.splitList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this error message is that Idris does not see that `xs = lhs ++ rhs`, you have to convince Idris.

First of all, let's prove the above fact as a separate lemma:

```
total
takeDropAppend : (n : Nat) -> (xs : List ty) -> xs = List.take n xs ++ List.drop n xs
takeDropAppend Z _ = Refl
takeDropAppend (S n) [] = Refl
takeDropAppend (S n) (x :: xs) = cong $ takeDropAppend n xs
```

Now we can make use of it as follows:

```
total
splitList : (xs: List ty) -> SplitList xs
splitList [ ] = Null
splitList [x] = Singleton
splitList xs =
  let
    mid = divNatNZ (List.length xs) 2 SIsNotZ
  in
    rewrite takeDropAppend mid xs in
    Pair (List.take mid xs) (List.drop mid xs)
```

I changed `div` into `divNatNZ` to make the function total and took a shortcut, replacing `lhs` and `rhs` with their definitions. I should have used the (more efficient) `List.splitAt` standard function, but it would've  complicated the proof.